# Permutation with Repetition Index Conversion

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multisets

I'm looking for the equation to determine the index of a permutation with repetition with known parameters.

For example:
A total of $9$ values, $4$ A's and $5$ B's
Gives a total of $126$ permutations with repetition. $$\frac{9!}{4! \cdot 5!} = 126$$

The Zero-based lexicographical order goes from 0 = AAAABBBBB to 125 = BBBBBAAAA
This data set is trivial enough that I just generated all the values with code, but large data sets are impractical.
I know that index 76 = BABABABAB since I have a list of answers, but I don't want to generate a partial or a full list.

How do I direclty convert any sequence such as BABABABAB to the permutation with repetition index?
How do I direclty do the reverse and convert the permutation with repetition index back to the sequence?

I'm looking for the equations / methods to use in a non-trivial example.

Lexicographical order is prefered, but not required as long as the method can convert in both directions (Sequence => Index and Index => Sequence).

Comment: [Find n-th lexicographically permutation of a string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-n-th-lexicographically-permutation-string-set-2/) supposedly runs in $O(n)$ time and space. For the other direction, see: [Lexicographical rank of a string with duplicate characters](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879429/318073).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-n-th-lexicographically-permutation-string-set-2/  Is close to what I'm looking for, thank you. Unfortunately it indexes by all permutations and not the reduced set specifying the repetition. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I tested both links (both directions I linked in my previous comment) and they work with duplicates (that is, they work with your example $77 = \text{BABABABAB}$). Note that it is $1$ more than $76$ because it is counted from $1$, not from $0$.

Comment: @Vepir simply stating it is O(n) is very misleading. It runs in $O(n)$ where $n$ is the $n^{th}$ permutation. That means $n$ is a factorial, which of course is a very large number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Forward conversion** was explained in "[Lexicographical rank of a string with duplicate characters](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879429/318073)". In short, I'm referencing [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1797885/318073) from that question:

> If the $i$th character is repeated $n_i$ times, then the total number of permutations is given by:
>
> $$ \frac{(n_1+n_2+\dots+n_m)!}{n_1!\cdot n_2! \cdot \space ... \space \cdot n_m!} $$
>
> We can at $k$th step consider the $k$th character of the given string and fix all characters before it. Now, if you replace this character with any of the preceding characters, then each of the possible permutations will precede the given permutation.
>
> We can calculate the number of such permutations with the given formula. Summing these calculations over all steps will give the total number of preceding permutations to the given permutation, which is the number we are after.

I've implemented this in python and tested it on your example: (*proof of concept*)

```
from math import factorial
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter

def lexicographical_index(string):
    [rank, l, freqs] = [0, len(string), Counter(string)]
    min_ord = min([ord(key) for key in freqs.keys()])
    for n in range(l):
        fsum = sum([freqs[chr(j)] for j in range(min_ord,ord(string[n]))])
        fprod = reduce(lambda x,y: y*x, [factorial(v) for v in freqs.values()])
        freqs[string[n]] -= 1;
        rank += ((fsum * factorial(l-n-1)) // fprod)
    return rank

print(lexicographical_index("babababab"))
```

which returns the expected result:

```
76
```

and should run in $O(m\cdot n)$ where $m$ is the number of unique chars among the $n$ chars.

**The backward conversion** uses the same idea. This time around, we are fixing characters from smallest to largest and counting the possible permutations until the count exceeds our index, until we fix (find) every character.

This was additionally explained and implemented in:

- "[Find n-th lexicographically permutation of a string | Set 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-n-th-lexicographically-permutation-string-set-2/)" from geeksforgeeks.org.
- [Algorithm for finding multiset permutation given lexicographic index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24506460/5821790) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Note that if all characters of your string are distinct (no duplicates), then we are permuting sets instead of multisets and the solution can be more efficient. See [How to find the next higher permutation out of a fixed group of digits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1400468/318073) where they discuss the Factorial number system and the Lehmer code.

Comment: Your code looks very elegant, but I'm not familiar with Python. Are you able to show this in VB.Net or C++ or even add a few comments. I assume it is doing the same thing as the link you provided but looks more robust as it isn't using a do while loop.

Comment: @cadthat It works the same as the C++ code that is linked in that answer I linked (You can see the C++ code [at the end of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879429/lexicographical-rank-of-a-string-with-duplicate-characters/1797885#1797885)). It's just that python has "list comprehension" and ready things like "sum" and "reduce", so those for and while loops are hidden in one or two lines. (The only difference I can think of is that I use a dictionary instead of an array, for the frequencies of characters.)

Comment: @cadthat I added comments to my new version of the code that you can see [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Q1FVw6NS) which has syntax highlight. :)

Comment: Your help has been exceptional. Thank you. I've been creating my code in vb.net and tested it on the 126 permutation with repetition example but ran into a problem with 91 of the 126 that they are low by 1 to 5. Would you mind checking index 11 aabbaabbb is low by 1 and index 125 bbbbbaaaa is low by 5; . I want to know that I have a bug to fix for sure. Index 76 comes out correct just like expected.

Comment: @cadthat You can run my code and compare the results. It [works fine for me](https://repl.it/repls/DarkorchidUltimateCells#main.py), you must have a bug in your vb.net implementation. Are you sure your factorials aren't overflowing and your division is not rounding anything.

Comment: Thank you, I'll chase it down.

Comment: That was awsome that I could run your python code online! I found I had an order of operation error in the formula part. I needed to multiply by fsum before integer dividing.

Comment: @cadthat Yes, online interpreters and compilers exist for all common programming languages. I'm glad you sorted it out, this was a fun problem for me :)

Comment: @Vepir What if we want all the permutations with limited repetitions? Like all the variations between 0000000000 and 9999999999 with 5 repetitions in each variation?
This is the question that I've asked:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247472/permutations-with-global-limited-repetition-without-the-need-for-providing-digit

Comment: @Eftekhari I have commented on your question.

Comment: @Vepir Thank you...