# Generating permutation "number" for specific permutation, and then generate the permuation with the number and the set, with duplicate elements

Tags: optimization, permutations, computer-science

**A.**
Given a set where some elements appear more than once and a specific permutation, is it possible to assign that permutation an unique number("permutation id") without needing to calculate every permutation and where the number is in the minimum range?

and

**B.**
Given a set and a "permutation id", is it possible to rebuild the actual permutation without brute-forcing it by calculating all permutations?

> Example
>
> The set A,A,B has 3 (3!/2!) permutations: AAB,ABA,BAA. Then the
> "permutation id" will be between 1-3 not 1-6
>
> so with the set A,A,B and the id 3 you should get (for instance) BAA.

I know this is easy to do if you just list all the permutations, remove the duplicates but for a non-trivial set that is unfeasible with a computer.

I started to think about this the other day and did some research, but all I could find were algorithms to list a random or all permutations.

Thanks

Comment: Does this [Permutation with Repetition Index Conversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3802978/318073) answer your questions?

Comment: Do you just need to determine if it's possible, or do you need to actually do it? You need to assign an ordering to the permutations, which isn't too hard.